# Perform a click programmatically in a Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, sendinput

I'm trying to port a WPF application to a Windows 8.1 App. In this application I use SendInput to move the mouse and to perform different kind of clicks (left, right, double...) inside or outside of the application window.
This is how I import the unmanaged function (together with some structs):

```
internal static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, ref NativeStructs.Input pInputs, int cbSize);

    }

    internal static class NativeStructs
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct Input
        {
            public NativeEnums.SendInputEventType type;
            public MouseInput mouseInput;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct MouseInput
        {
            public int dx;
            public int dy;
            public uint mouseData;
            public NativeEnums.MouseEventFlags dwFlags;
            public uint time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }
    }

    internal static class NativeEnums
    {
        internal enum SendInputEventType : int
        {
            Mouse = 0,
            Keyboard = 1,
            Hardware = 2,
        }

        internal enum MetricIndex : int
        {
            SM_CXSCREEN = 0,
            SM_CYSCREEN = 1
        }

        [Flags]
        internal enum MouseEventFlags : uint
        {
            Move = 0x0001,
            LeftDown = 0x0002,
            LeftUp = 0x0004,
            RightDown = 0x0008,
            RightUp = 0x0010,
            MiddleDown = 0x0020,
            MiddleUp = 0x0040,
            XDown = 0x0080,
            XUp = 0x0100,
            Wheel = 0x0800,
            Absolute = 0x8000,
        }
    }
```

And this is an example of how I call it:

```
    public static void LeftDown()
    {
        NativeStructs.Input input = new NativeStructs.Input
        {
            type = NativeEnums.SendInputEventType.Mouse,
            mouseInput = new NativeStructs.MouseInput
            {
                dx = 0,
                dy = 0,
                mouseData = 0,
                dwFlags = NativeEnums.MouseEventFlags.Absolute | NativeEnums.MouseEventFlags.LeftDown,
                time = 0,
                dwExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero,
            },
        };

        NativeMethods.SendInput(1, ref input, Marshal.SizeOf(input));
        _isLeftDown = true;
    }
```

This methods used to work perfectly in the WPF application, but in the Windows 8.1 App only the mouse movement works.
The click isn't performed neither outside the app window nor inside of it. The code is executed and no exception or error is thrown.
I've also tried to use mouse_event, but the situation is the same.
I think it is a limitation imposed somehow to the apps, but is there a workaround for this situation?

p.s. I know the function LeftDown() performs only the mouse_down, that is not the problem;-)

Comment: Did you read about `AttachThreadInput`, `keybd_event` and `mouse_event` functions? `keybd_event` doesn't support all Unicode keys, but it doesn't require `AttachThreadInput` at all.